# Dynamic where clause by reading values inside a table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dynamic, where-clause

Can you help me to get the student 'Lindsay' class name and session description values reading Rules table
Table name, 
columnName and 
value 
columns?

[image]

Comment: Yes Correct :), it should output  like that, but the FROM clause it should be read from rule table.

Select Firstname, ClassName,Description
from
<
i'm not clear how to relate it with Rule table with TableName , ColumnName  ,value
to reach Class and session table
( clients can configure rules on rules table)
>
Where 
<This also should be generated from rule table 
classID=1 and SessionID=2>

Comment: Are you trying to join the tables together?

Comment: Yes trying to join, by reading the rule table. First reading the tables which need to be join through Rule table, then I have to join.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer Coool :),That would be the final SQL i am going to make it, but lets say the inner join tables  are stored on rule table. My question is how to construct that SQL, by reading them and finaly coming to above SQL. Can i achieve that ?

Comment: @razor what kind of answer are you looking for? One giving you hints on how to solve this yourself or one that provides you with the SQL?

Comment: Hi @Dennis1679 looking for a SQL, wondering how it can be achieved

Comment: It's more like this. How can i do mine.
https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-dynamic-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.FirstName, b.ClassName, c.Description FROM Student a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rule r1 ON a.RuleID = r1.RuleID AND r1.[Table Name] = 'Class' AND r1.[Column Name] = 'ClassID'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rule r2 ON a.RuleID = r2.RuleID AND r2.[Table Name] = 'Session' AND r2.[Column Name] = 'SessionID'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Class b ON b.ClassID = r1.Value
LEFT OUTER JOIN Session c ON c.SessionID = r2.Value
```

If it needs to be dynamically reading the rule table, then you could use dynamic sql and cursor through the 'Rule' table first and just have the 'r1' join with 'r1.[Table Name]' and 'r1.[Column Name]' being dynamically populated from the cursor.